# @XmlRootElement vs @JacksonXmlRootElement

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jackson, jaxb, xml-binding

What is exact difference between `@XmlRootElement` `@JacksonXmlRootElement`?

I know @XmlRootElement is generic, But when I check package structure both are different.

So there must be some advantage and disadvantage while using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JacksonXmlRootElement](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlRootElement.html) allow to define name of root level

> define name of root element used for the root-level object when serialized

Here's the reason for adding [@JacksonXmlRootElement](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/2)

> JAXB allows you to override the name of the root element (using
>   @XmlRootElement when generating XML. For example, rendering this class
>   to XML:
>
> @JsonIgnoreProperties( {"meal", "notMeal", "mealNameDisplay"} ) public
>   class MealEvent...
>
> Generates XML like this:
>
> lunch ... But I'd like the root element to be 'meal' instead of
>   'MealEvent'.
>
> FWIW, I tried the wild guess using @JsonTypeName( "meal" ) as well –
>   it had no effect.
>
> Implemented: now there is @JacksonXmlRootElement (named similar to JAXB annotation, just with "Jackson" prefix to reduce confusion).